# vb.net 2012 Error 1 Resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" cannot be found.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In a vb.net 2012 vb.net desktop application that I am opening for the first time, I am getting the following error and warning message:
Error   1   Resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" cannot be found.

Warning 2   A custom tool 'VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator' is associated with file 'My Project\Resources.resx', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

I tried to run the custom tool that was suggested in the warning message and that did not help.
Thus can you tell me what I can do to get the Resources.resx file that is missing?

Comment: By 'opening' do you mean when you run the app?  Are you trying to access the Resx file from your app?

Comment: Whomever checked-in the project surely forgot to check in the file.  The "custom tool" it is talking about uses the .resx file as *input*.  You probably don't have the My Project\Resources.Designer.vb file either, the output file, makes it hard to figure out how to recreate the .resx file properly.   You're kinda screwed, use source control history to find the dev machine that might still have the file on its disk.  Have a good talking to its owner.

Comment: The person that created the file was a contractor that is no longer employed in my company. However I think I might know what computer the resource file was created on. Should I check that computer somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue by copying "My Project" folder from different project and pasting it into project where I had this error.

You also need to change root namespaces from files inside so it matches your solution's root namespace where error occurs.

Comment: This worked for me.  Bonus if you can use a backup of the "My Project" from the same project before it got removed somehow.  I just pasted it in and it was ready to go.